# Highcharts map navigation Zooming option to outer button

Tags: highcharts

I have created a Live stock Graph Using Highcharts. I did that Zoom option using map.js, Its working good with their default buttons like "+" and "-". My question is How can i create the same Zooming Option using Outer Buttons.

My Code is

```
 mapNavigation: {
              enabled: true,
              buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'top'
              }
            }
```

Here the link to image
https://s32.postimg.org/jyextt0rp/

[image]

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? You could assign click event to your custom buttons that will trigger same logic/function as used with map navigation.